# Finding correct of PHP binary - exec()

Tags: php, exec

I'm trying to execute a separate PHP script from within a PHP page. After some research, I found that it is possible using the `exec()` function.

I also referenced [**this SO solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550258/1223045) to find the path of the php binary. So my full command looks like this:

```
$file_path = '192.168.1.13:8080/doSomething.php';
$cmd = PHP_BINDIR.'/php '.$file_path; // PHP_BINDIR prints /usr/local/bin
exec($cmd, $op, $er);
echo $er; // prints 127 which turns out to be invalid path/typo
```

### doSomething.php

```
echo "Hi there!";
```

I know `$file_path` is a correct path because if I open its value; i.e. `192.168.1.13:8080/doSomething.php`, I do get "Hi there!" printed out. This makes me assume that `PHP_BINDIR.'/php'` is wrong.

Should I be trying to get the path of the php binary in some other way?

Comment: you execute commands just by using backticks. e.g. \`php 192.168.1.13:8080/doSomething.php\` . see that i put 'php' at the front of your path.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are requesting is accessible via a web server, not as a local PHP script. Thus you can get the result of the script simply by

```
$output = file_get_contents($file_path);
```

If you however for some reason really have to `exec` the file, then you must provide a **full path** to that file in your server directory structure instead of server **URL**:

```
$file_path = '/full/path/to/doSomething.php';
$cmd = PHP_BINDIR.'/php '.$file_path;
exec($cmd, $op, $er);
```

Comment: I don't really need to get the contents of `$file_path`. I just used a simple "Hi there" to test if `exec` works properly. I'll be replacing that code with a more complex code which I need to be able to run in background.

Comment: PHP does not natively provide threading functionallity. If you either `exec` or use `file_get_contents` it will be invoked in that exact spot, and rest of your script will wait for it to finish. If you want that script to execute in background, then there is some additional coding involved.

Comment: By full path, do you mean something like this : `var/www/somefolder...`?

Comment: Yes (just with the leading slash `/` in front). Additionally if that script would only be executed from within another script, than don't expose it via web server by moving it outside the root of host directory.